# Ocaml list function

Tags: list, function, ocaml

I have some "problems" with Ocaml functions.

Define function `all_odd`, which, for a given matrix as a parameter check if all the elements
are odd.

```
val all_odd : int list list -> bool = <fun>
```

Example:

```
#let matrix1 = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]];;
val matrix1 : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]]

#all_odd matrix1;;
- : bool = false;
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us what you have.

Comment: You should try to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that problem in many way, but the best approach would be to decomposite the problem into simple ones.

- Step 1: What's smallest problem to solve? How to check if a number is odd

  `x mod 2 != 0`
- Step 2: How to use it for a whole list of numbers

  `let isOdd list = List.for_all (fun x -> x mod 2 != 0) list`
- Step 3: How   to use it for a matrix

---

```
let all_odd matrix =
    let isOdd list = List.for_all (fun x -> x mod 2 != 0) list in
    List.for_all isOdd matrix
```

Makes sense?

Comment: Discourage using `!=` operator, use `<>` when it does not matter.

Comment: or `let all_odd = List.for_all (List.for_all (fun x -> x mod 2 != 0))` if you want to be concise